# Geocode: Transform NSArray to NSString

Tags: ios, iphone, geocoding

I have a variable declared as `NSArray` in `.h` file  & synthesized in `.m`

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray *placemarksArray;  //.h file
@synthesize placemarksArray; //.m

-(BOOL)searchDisplayController:(UISearchDisplayController *)controller shouldReloadTableForSearchString:(NSString *)searchString 
{
    if (!geocoder)
    geocoder = [[CLGeocoder alloc] init];
    [geocoder geocodeAddressString:searchString completionHandler:^(NSArray* placemarks, NSError* error){

if ([placemarks count] > 0) {

        for (CLPlacemark* aPlacemark in placemarks)
        {

            self.street = placemark.thoroughfare;
            self.city = placemark.locality;
            self.state = placemark.administrativeArea;
            self.zip = placemark.postalCode;


            NSMutableString *result = [NSMutableString string];
            if (self.street)
                [result appendString:self.street];
            if (self.street && (self.city || self.state || self.zip))
                [result appendString:@", "];
            if (self.city)
                [result appendString:self.city];
            if (self.city && self.state)
                [result appendString:@", "];
            if (self.state)
                [result appendString:self.state];
            if (self.zip)
                [result appendFormat:@" %@", self.zip];
            [self.placemarksArray addObject:result];
            NSLog(@"%@", result);

            [self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView reloadData];
        }
    }

}];
return NO;
```

}

Question: How can I set `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath` to show `placemarksArray` in the `tableView`?

```
    - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

Code above was taken from Apple:
[About Geocoder Objects](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/LocationAwarenessPG/UsingGeocoders/UsingGeocoders.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009497-CH4-SW5)

Comment: You code cellForRowAtIndexPath and use the index path to index your array and extract the info.

Comment: [cell.textLabel setText:[placemarksArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add to your `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method:

```
cell.textLabel.text = [placemarksArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

What this will do is set the text of each cell equal to the text that is at the nth index of the `placemarksArray.` For instance, the cell at row 3 will have the text from index 3 of the array.

Comment: *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 1 beyond bounds [0 .. 0]'  I know there is an object in the Array for sure.  Am I getting this error b/c I need to assign placemarksArray lastObject:nil ?  If so, where do I do that?  Thanks.

Comment: @user1107173 - You're getting that error because you're trying to use an array that doesn't contain any information.

Comment: @HotLicks The array is not empty.  It has an object.  I did an NSLog with placemarksArray.count and it returns 1.

Comment: @user1107173 - The array you're indexing is empty.  It may be that you have a *different* array, with the same variable name, that contains something, but the one you're indexing is empty.  NSLog it just before the index op.